# backbone view is triggering the event delegate many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, view

Hi so I have a view in backbone similar to this

```
app.FileListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'list-group-item clearfix',
    events: {
        'click .download-action': 'download'
    },
    template: _.template(
            "<div class='pull-left' style='width: 80%'>\n\
                <%= name %><br><span style='font-size: 10px;'><%= path %></span>\n\
            </div>\n\
            <div class='pull-right' style='width: 20%'>\n\
                <div class='dropdown'>\n\
                    <button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>\n\
                      Actions\n\
                      <span class='caret'></span>\n\
                    </button>\n\
                    <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>\n\
                      <li class='download-action' data-id='<%= id %>' data-accountid='<%= accountid %>' role='presentation'><a class='super-anchor' role='menuitem' tabindex='-1' href='#'>Download</a></li>\n\
                    </ul>\n\
                </div>\n\
            </div>"
            ),
    initialize: function () {
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
        return this;
    },
    download: function (event) {
        //console.log(this.$el.find('.download-action-link').data('id'));
        var el = this.$el.find('.download-action');
        var id = el.data('id');
        var accountid = el.data('accountid');
        var url = app.config.get('apiURL');
        var apiKey = app.config.get('apiKey');

        console.log(el.prop('tagName'));

        $.ajax(url + '/accounts/' + accountid + '/links', {
            data: {
                'file_id': id, 'direct': true
            },
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'ApiKey ' + apiKey
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.active) {
                    var a = el.find('.super-anchor');
                    console.log(a);
                    //change this part
                    //a.attr('href', data.url).trigger('click');
                    //to this
                    a.attr('href', data.url).on('click', function(event){
                      event.preventDefault();
                      event.stopPropagation();
                    })[0].click();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

the idea is that when I click the LI with "download-action" class the download method is called in my view, that should pick a url from the ajax call and then added to the href attr of the anchot tag which is under the LI and after that I trigger the anchor click, but when I do that the download method start to be called in loop indefinitely, can some how tell me why is this happening?? thanks!!!!

Comment: You should consider moving the templates to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the triggered click event is being propagated up to li.download-action which then starts the ajax download function all over again. A solution would be to use window.location.href to navigate the user to the new url or to move that link out side li.download-action.

Comment: Hey, u point me in the right direction, however the solution was a bit different, basically I added an event handler to the anchor tag itself to stop the propagation, all working as expected now, thanks!